# Should I go with MySQL or MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm in the planing phase of the development of an mobile app and I need your help to decide wheather I should go with MySQL or MongoDB. First let me describe the data:

I have a set of Items (e.g. movies) that users will be able to browse and score in different ways. The total number of Items is approximately 20 000 and it will not grow or shrink.

Each user will be able to score each item (numerical value) and write a comment assigned to each item. I expect that the average user will score maybe 40 different items, but my hopes are higher!

The typcial queries will be

1. Give me all items that satisfies some criteria and let me browse them. Example: Give me all Thrillers produced in Europe during the 00s.
2. Give me all movies that a particular user has scored.

I would also like to do some server side calculations e.g. average score for each movie, and each time a user sumbits a new score for an item this average should be updated.

For MySQL I would have a database with 3 different tables for this (Items, Users, Scores) and for MongoDB I'm considering a database with 1 collection, like this:

```
{
  "name":"Inception"
  "year":2010
  "director":"Christopher Nolan"
  "scores" : [
    {
       "user_id": 1234
       "scoreA" : 3,
       "scoreB" : 5,
       "scoreC" : 4,

    },
    {
       "user_id": 1235
       "scoreA" : 4,
       "scoreB" : 3
    },
}
{
  "name":"Titanic"
  "year":1997
  "director":"James Cameron"
  "scores" : [
    {
       "user_id": 1201
       "scoreB" : 5,
       "scoreC" : 5
    },
    {
       "user_id": 1220
       "scoreA" : 4,
       "scoreC" : 5
    },
}
...
```

**Question:** Given my use case, does it matter if I use MySQL or MongoDB?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Go with a relational database like mysql, there is no need to use MongoDb here unless you just wanna try it out.

As generell advice use NoSQL (especially MongoDb) when you can't improve your RDMS anymore.

Also take a look at this wonderful presentation: http://www.thedotpost.com/2015/06/neha-narula-consistency-and-candy-crush

Comment: This answer couldn't be more opinionated and factless even if I personally tried.

Comment: I agree. NoSQL databases are not about "when you can't improve your RDMS anymore", or a bigger sibling to "regular" databases. They're about a completely different paradigm and have different uses, just like any other tools. You wouldn't generally suggest "when you can't improve your C++ anymore, use Prolog", would you? At least I hope so.